# Why doesn't my freshly painted door fit back in the frame?

Tags: doors

I took off a hollow core interior door to paint it. Very thin coats (this is only the second time it's been painted since contractors built house. I know they only sprayed 1 very thin coat). Now the door doesn't seem to fit as well. I did new hinges -same size just different color. I know I can plane it for better fit but I want to know why the door doesn't fit right back in. The new coats of paint are not too thick so it's not the paint job. Ideas?  I have more doors to redo so I want to avoid this problem again.

Comment: Were the hinges set properly?

Comment: Did you use long 3" screws on the hinges, or short ones that came with the hinges?

Comment: Any chance the door sat outside and was at a dramatically different temperature or humidity than the inside?

Comment: Did you buy heavy duty (thicker hinges) than the originals?

Comment: You might be surprised how a couple of coats of paint can cause a close fitting door to bind. Where exactly is the door hitting the frame?

Comment: Can you describe how big the gap/overlap is along each side of the door to the frame?

Answer (score 3):

You say

> The new coats of paint are not too thick so it's not the paint job.

and this is a common misconception. Yes, it looks like the paint is negligibly thin but it actually adds up. When a door is constructed it has size that allow for painting it once, maybe twice, and then a new layer of paint will prevent it from closing.

You should have cleaned the previous paint off the door edges.

Answer (score 0):

Since hollow core doors aren't made of the finest materials, is it possible that even your minimal amount of paint caused swelling?  I could imagine that even just a bit of swelling over a 30 inch door width could cause it to jam.